# funcion perdidas javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo este problema, creo que lo estoy pensando mal.

Ana, viendo que somos tan productivos, nos pidió algo más: ahora quiere saber en cuántos meses de un período hubo pérdida.

Decimos que hay pérdida en un período cuando el saldo es menor a cero.

Escribí la función cantidadDeMesesConPerdida. La estructura de la función es parecida a las que venimos haciendo, ¡animate!

```js
function cantidadDeMesesConPerdida(unPeriodo) {
  var cantidad = unPeriodo.length;
  var saldoConPerdida =[];
  for (let i = 0; i < cantidad ; i++) {
    if (unPeriodo[i] <= 0){
      saldoConPerdida.push(unPeriodo[i]);
    }
  }
  return saldoConPerdida ;
}
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
La función cantidadDeMesesConPerdida([1]) debe retornar 0
La función cantidadDeMesesConPerdida([]) debe retornar 0
La función cantidadDeMesesConPerdida([10, -10, 2, 100]) debe retornar 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Estás retornando el arreglo completo:

```
return saldoConPerdida;
```

Debería de ser la cantidad de meses:

```
return saldoConPerdida.length;
```

También sugiero que se cambie el nombre de la variable a `mesesConPerdida` para que sea más legible.

Comment: Genial. Lo arreglé. Muchas gracias por el consejo de cambiar el nombre de la variable.

Comment: Hay algo que no llego a comprender del todo... dice el usuario en el primer ejemplo de retorno que debe retornar 0, y se hace el ejemplo con un arreglo que contiene un elemento, pero el valor de retorno ha de ser 0 en ese caso, así que realmente esto de retornar simplemente la cantidad de elementos en el array no se si sea lo que quiere el usuario...

Comment: @Riven, En mi respuesta sólo incluí el final de la función. En realidad los cálculos dentro de la función estaban bien.

function cantidadDeMesesConPerdida(unPeriodo) {
  var cantidad = unPeriodo.length;
  var saldoConPerdida =[];
  for (let i = 0; i < cantidad ; i++) {
    if (unPeriodo[i] <= 0){
      saldoConPerdida.push(unPeriodo[i]);
    }
  }
  return saldoConPerdida.length;
}

Comment: Ah cierto, no vi bien la condicion que puso el OP, si, es correcto.